# Complex animation of objects' images using Core Animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, touch-event

I got 5 objects with their images. I add them to array and shuffle them.

```
// Adding Things to Things Strip
[thingStrip removeAllObjects];
for (Thing *i in myThings) {
    [self addThing:[i icon]];
}

// Randomizing Things' order in the Things Strip
for (int x = 0; x<thingStrip.count; x++) {
    int randInt = (arc4random() % (thingStrip.count - x)) + x;
    [thingStrip exchangeObjectAtIndex:x withObjectAtIndex:randInt];
}

// Adding Things' Images
for (int i=0; i<thingStrip.count; i++) {
    UIImage *thingImage = thingStrip[i];
```

Then I add them to `UIImage` and create `CALayers` with them.
All I need is:

1. Make them move from right to left continuously without any gaps.
2. Scale them smoothly from 80x53 at right position to 120x80 at left position
3. Make opacity from 0.5 at right position to 1.0 at left position.
4. Each iteration lasts 0.5 seconds.
5. Whole `animation` lasts 5 seconds or stop on screen touch.
6. After `animation` is stopped I need left object proceed to the left end of the screen.
7. After `animation` is stopped I need to know which object image stopped at left end of the screen to use its' object data later.

For now I can do moving animation, but my solution is not so good.

```
// Adding Things' Images
for (int i=0; i<thingStrip.count; i++) {
    UIImage *thingImage = thingStrip[i];
    //for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    //{ 
        CALayer *thingFrame = [CALayer layer];
        thingFrame.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 53.0);
        thingFrame.position = CGPointMake(i*thingFrame.frame.size.width, 515.0);
        //thingFrame.position = CGPointMake(i*thingFrame.frame.size.width + j * thingStrip.count * thingFrame.frame.size.width, 515.0);
        thingFrame.contents = (id)thingImage.CGImage;
        [thingFrame setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:thingFrame];

        CGFloat currentPosition = [[thingFrame valueForKeyPath:@"position.x"] floatValue];
        CGFloat newPosition = currentPosition - thingStrip.count * thingFrame.frame.size.width;

        CABasicAnimation *thingMoveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
         thingMoveAnimation.duration = 0.5f;
        thingMoveAnimation.repeatDuration = 5.0f;
        thingMoveAnimation.delegate = self;
        thingMoveAnimation.fromValue = @(currentPosition);
        thingMoveAnimation.toValue = @(newPosition);
        thingMoveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        [thingFrame addAnimation:thingMoveAnimation forKey:@"position.x"];
    //}
}
```

This code works only if I use for loop with 'j' (commented one) which adds 5 of each image. Only then I get smooth moving animation without any gaps. I guess it's not right solution. When I use only one for loop, I get animation of 5 images moving left again and again, but not continuously one after another.

I don't have working solution for scaling and opacity animation and I don't know how to end it by `touching` the screen and get needed image data. 
I was trying to find similar solution for a while but found nothing.

I'm looking for help with working code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful using animations from within loops. From my experience all the running animations will be terminated the moment your loop starts over. Try running them in a dedicated thread with 'performSelectorInBackground
 withObject:'

Comment: No, you can't run animations from a background thread. You need to add a delay to the animation start, or trigger each new animation from the completion method of the previous animation.

Comment: As I can see, noone can help me yet. I'm trying to find different ways to achieve my goals. Should I use block animation instead? Anв how to use it for all my layers simultaneously? I still need help.